# Why there is an error in a wix project?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I am using Wix toolset 3.8 and  I try to create an msi project. While building I have an error like this one:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.   Analyzer    light.exe   0
```

Has anybody faced with such a problem? Any help will be appreciated! I am a beginner in this field...
Here is the source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <?define ProductName="Traffic_Analyzer" ?>
  <?define ProductVersion="1.0.0.0" ?>
  <?define ProductCode="*"?>
  <?define UpgradeCode="9e36a864-f98e-446a-b2e6-dd77567a4031"?>
  <?define Manufacturer="Leanenka_Dzianis"?>
  <?define licenseRtf="C:\Users\DzianisL\Desktop\license.rtf"?>

  <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1049" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
           Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <!--1033 on 1049 - Russian language maintaines-->
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.ProductName)">

          <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="*">
            <File Id='Sniffer' DiskId='1' Source='C:\Users\DzianisL\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Sniffer\Sniffer\bin\Release\Sniffer.exe'/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
          <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutSniffer" Guid="4CEBD68F-E933-47f9-B02C-A4FC69FDB551">
            <Shortcut Id="ShortcutSniffer"
                 Name="Sniffer"
                 Description="$(var.ProductName)"
                 Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]Sniffer.exe"
                 WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>


    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutSniffer" />
    </Feature>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" ></Property>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Overridable="yes" Value="$(var.licenseRtf)"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>




  </Product>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open bug report](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4485/) in the WiX issue tracker that indicates that the error is related to your RTF file ending with a null character.

I would check whether your license.rtf ends with null end then truncate that character from the file (or create a new RTF file without null)

Comment: Thank you, you are quite right!
I just opened the license with Notepad and there I found the NULL character. After its removal everything worked!

Comment: @DziLean: Glad it worked and welcome to Stack Overflow. You can help others with the same problem by upvoting useful answers and by accepting the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I've never seen this bug.  FWIW I always recommend spinning up a Windows XP VM and using wordpad to create the RTF.  The reason for this is the RichText control included in Windows Installer is very old and picky so the least common denominator approach helps head off issues down the road.  One would probably never end up with an RTF terminated with a null character if this approach is followed.

Comment: I'm getting that error in version 4.  Now there is license.txt.  No null chars.

Answer (score -2):

I resolved this error:

> '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character

by commenting this line:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```